Making JS specs work with headless Chrome
I have a Sinatra app with a Rspec suite and now I need to run it on GitHub Actions. My workflow looks like:
name: continuous-integration
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04

    services:
      mssql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU31-GDR2-ubuntu-18.04
        env:
          SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
          ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        ports:
          - 1433:1433

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cache FreeTDS
        id: cache-freetds
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: freetds-1.4.17
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-freetds

      - name: Install FreeTDS
        if: steps.cache-freetds.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -y install wget build-essential libc6-dev
          sudo wget http://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.4.17.tar.gz
          sudo tar -xzf freetds-1.4.17.tar.gz
          cd freetds-1.4.17
          sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-tdsver=7.3
          sudo make
          sudo make install

      - name: Cache SqlPackage
        id: cache-sqlpackage
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: $HOME/sqlpackage
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sqlpackage

      - name: Install SqlPackage
        if: steps.cache-sqlpackage.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        uses: potatoqualitee/mssqlsuite@v1.7
        with:
          install: sqlpackage
          version: 2017

      - name: Create database
        run: sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'yourStrong(!)Password' -d tempdb -Q "CREATE DATABASE SEAVisionTEST;"

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          # ruby-version: from .ruby-version
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Run RSpec
        run: |
          bin/rspec spec --fail-fast --format progress
        env:
          RUBYOPT: -W0
          APP_ENV: test
          SQLSERVER_DATASERVER: localhost
          SQLSERVER_USERNAME: sa
          SQLSERVER_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
 
      - name: Publish code coverage
        uses: paambaati/codeclimate-action@v5.0.0
        env:
          CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID: ${{ secrets.CODE_CLIMATE_ID }}

Now, if I run it with headless Chrome:
require "capybara/rspec"
require "selenium-webdriver"

require File.expand_path("../application", __dir__)

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
  opts.add_argument("--headless") unless ENV["NOT_HEADLESS"]
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.server = :puma, {Silent: true}

Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application

The suite runs but the specs that rely on JS fail as the JS code is not executed.
If I run the suite with Chrome:
require "capybara/rspec"
require "selenium-webdriver"


require File.expand_path("../application", __dir__)


Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
Capybara.server = :puma, {Silent: true}

Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application

I get

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:
session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

In both cases, the suite passes without any issues on my development machine.
What am I missing here?
Should I install a JS runtime when using headless Chrome? I tried adding Node.js to my workflow apt-get install -y nodejs, but the result didn't change.
What can I do to make either scenario work?

I don't see you installing chrome anywhere. Do those images come with it already installed?

Yes, According to https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#browsers-and-drivers
